# Tkinter window in taskbar with overdirect True

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show my tkinter window icon in the taskbar when the window is not minimized ( the `.overrideredirect` is set to True ), i saw others questions like [Make tkinter Window appear in the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123663/make-tkinter-window-appear-in-the-taskbar)
 and [Tkinter, Windows: How to view window in windows task bar which has no title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786337/tkinter-windows-how-to-view-window-in-windows-task-bar-which-has-no-title-bar)
 but both have answers that includes the `ctypes` module, i was wondering if there is a simpler way for do this and maybe that works on other os too.

Here is the gui

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import os

x, y = 0, 0


def startMove(event):
    global x, y
    print(event.x_root, event.x, borderFrame.winfo_rootx())
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
def stopMove(event):
    global x, y
    x = None
    y = None
def moving(event):
    global x, y
    x_ = (event.x_root - x)
    y_ = (event.y_root - y)
    root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x_, y_))
def frame_mapped(e):
    print(e)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.state('normal')
def minimize(event):
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    #root.state('withdrawn')
    root.state('iconic')
def exitProgram(event):
    os._exit(0)
def hover(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="red")
def unhover(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="white")
def hoverMin(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="grey")
def unHoverMin(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="white")


root = Tk()
root.title("Draggable Root")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.overrideredirect(True)

borderFrame = Frame(root, width=500, height=600, bg="white")
borderFrame.pack_propagate(False)
borderFrame.pack(side=TOP)

holderFrame = Frame(borderFrame, width=500, height=570, bg="grey62")
holderFrame.pack_propagate(False)
holderFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

close = Label(root, font=("Arial", 11), bg="white", anchor=CENTER, text="X", cursor="hand2")
close.place(x=460, y=0, width=40, height=30)

min = Label(root, font=("Arial", 11), bg="white", anchor=CENTER, text="_", cursor="hand2")
min.place(x=420, y=0, width=40, height=30)

min.bind("<Enter>", hoverMin)
min.bind("<Leave>", unHoverMin)
min.bind("<Button-1>", minimize)
close.bind("<Enter>", hover)
close.bind("<Leave>", unhover)
close.bind("<Button-1>", exitProgram)
borderFrame.bind("<Button-1>", startMove)
borderFrame.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", stopMove)
borderFrame.bind("<B1-Motion>", moving)
borderFrame.bind("<Map>", frame_mapped)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get icon on alt-Tab then I can't really test that as I've Mac but it is showing in my command-tab which is pretty much same as alt-tab.

[image: Sample Image]

The only thing I change to get the window visible on my system is

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)
```

As on Mac just `root.overrideredirect(True)` hides the window

Comment: i don't want to change the tkinter icon, i wanto to show the icon in the taskbar when the window is not minimized

Comment: I changed my answer, but I'm not sure if this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
`root.iconbitmap("_full_path_to_icon_file")`
Eg: `root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")`
Or:`root.icontbitmap("_relative_path")`.
By relative path I mean if the icon image is present in your current folder and not somewhere else.

Comment: i don't want to change the tkinter icon, i wanto to show the icon in the taskbar when the window is not minimized