# Python tkinter overrideredirect hides in taskbar

Tags: python, tkinter

The `self.overrideredirect(True)` function, removes `titlebar` and `borders`.

But it also removes window from taskbar. And this is a problem for me.

Are there any way to show tkinter window in taskbar?

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lbl = Label(text="Window").pack(expand=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Window()
    win.overrideredirect(1)
    win.geometry("600x400+300+100")
    win.mainloop()
```

I'm using **Windows**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make tkinter Window appear in the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123663/make-tkinter-window-appear-in-the-taskbar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making Tkinter windows show up in the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066027/making-tkinter-windows-show-up-in-the-taskbar)