# When I switch to another app in PC my tkinter app doesn't stay or it vanishes

Tags: python, tkinter, minimize

Application doesnt stay in background as i switches to other app.I hope a quicker reply from the coders. But it works well if i minimze it will the minimize button.

What could be my mistake ,, or what could be the solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry("400x400")
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.resizable(False, False)


def close():
    root.destroy()

def minimizeWindow():
    root.withdraw()
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.iconify()

def check_map(event): # apply override on deiconify.
    if str(event) == "<Map event>":
        root.overrideredirect(1)
        print ('Deiconified', event)
    else:
        print ('Iconified', event)

bar_frame = tk.Frame(root)
bar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
bar_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# This appears to have the same results so not sure what the difference is from iconbitmap.
# root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon) 

tk.Button(bar_frame, text='x', command=close).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(bar_frame, text='-', command=minimizeWindow).grid(row=0, column=2)

root.bind('<Map>', check_map) # added bindings to pass windows status to function
root.bind('<Unmap>', check_map)

import mouse
wy=0
ex=0

def standard_bind():
   root.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e: event(e, Mode=True))

def event(widget, Mode=False):
    global ex, wy
    if Mode:
        ex = widget.x
        wy = widget.y
    root.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e: event(e))
    root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (mouse.get_position()[0]-ex, mouse.get_position()[1]-wy))
root.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e: event(e, Mode=True))
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: standard_bind())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't use `overrideredirect()` is the short and SIMPLE answer

Comment: i want to use it bro..

Comment: Instead of using `mouse.get_position()` you can use `root.winfo_pointerx()` and `root.winfo_winfo_pointery()`. Alternatively you can use `widget.x_root` and `widget.y_root` where `widget` is what you named the event (for some reason)

Comment: bors tell me someone who can fix my problem. i really need. thanks for your suggestions btw.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123663/make-tkinter-window-appear-in-the-taskbar
This solution solved my problem.