# App's icon is not show in taskbar because of Custom title bar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an code editor in which I want to custom title bar to match my app theme and I have created an custom title bar but my app is not showing in taskbar

If any external **libraries** are for this, Please tell me

What **libraries** I have to learn to solve my problem please tell me

how to show app icon on taskbar, Actually I have no idea about it
if you can solve it
Please help me to solve my problem

this is my full code(not full code but short version of real one):-

```
from tkinter import*
def move(e):
        xwin = root.winfo_x()
        ywin = root.winfo_y()
        startx = e.x_root
        starty = e.y_root
        ywin -= starty
        xwin -= startx
        def move_(e):
            root.geometry(f"+{e.x_root + xwin}+{e.y_root + ywin}")
        startx = e.x_root
        starty = e.y_root
        frame.bind("<B1-Motion>",move_)
def minieme1_(event=None):
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.overrideredirect(False)
        root.state("iconic")
def frame_map(event=None):
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.overrideredirect(True)
        root.state("normal")
        root.call()
def minimefunction(event=None):
        global size
        if size:
            root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height-40}+0+0")
            minimsi.config(text=" \u2752 ")
            size = False
        else:
            root.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
            minimsi.config(text=" \u25a0 ")
            size = True
            
def quitApp():
    root.destroy()
def close_blink(event=None):
    close_button.config(bg="red")
def close_blink1(event=None):
    close_button.config(bg="gray19")
def minimsi_blink(event=None):
    minimsi.config(bg="gray29")
def minimsi_blink1(event=None):
    minimsi.config(bg="gray19")
def minimsi1_blink(event=None):
    minimsi1.config(bg="gray29")
def minimsi1_blink1(event=None):
    minimsi1.config(bg="gray19")
root = Tk()
size = True
app_width = 600
app_height = 500
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
print(screen_width,screen_height)
x = (screen_width/2) - (app_width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (app_height/2)
root.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
root.overrideredirect(True)
frame = Frame(root,bg="gray29")

Label(frame,text="My App",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray29",fg="white").pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
close_button = Button(frame,text=" X ",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",relief=GROOVE,borderwidth=0,command=quitApp)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
minimsi = Button(frame,text=" \u25a0 ",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",relief=GROOVE,borderwidth=0,command=minimefunction)
minimsi.pack(side=RIGHT)
minimsi1 = Button(frame,text=" - ",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",relief=GROOVE,borderwidth=0,command=minieme1_)
minimsi1.pack(side=RIGHT)
frame.pack(fill=X)

yscroll = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL)
yscroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
editor = Text(font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",insertbackground="white",borderwidth=0,yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
yscroll.config(command=editor.yview)
editor.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)
root.config(bg="gray19")

frame.bind("<Button-1>",move)
frame.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
# minimsi1.bind("<Button-1>",minieme1_)
frame.bind("<Map>",frame_map)
close_button.bind("<Enter>",close_blink)
close_button.bind("<Leave>",close_blink1)
minimsi.bind("<Enter>",minimsi_blink)
minimsi.bind("<Leave>",minimsi_blink1)
minimsi1.bind("<Enter>",minimsi1_blink)
minimsi1.bind("<Leave>",minimsi1_blink1)


root.mainloop()
```

You can see the problem in this image:-
[image]

Comment: [General way around it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066027). A [windows specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852693) way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, this may not be the best approach to achieve OP`s goal, but I'm sticking to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852693/13629335) because:

- There are several question with this example on StackOverflow
- It shows a basic knowledge that is important for deeper digging.

**The improvement of this code to the original is that the style applies again after you iconify it and bring that windows back up.**

See the twitch of this example is how the taskbar keeps track of the application. There is a [good article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031229-00/?p=41283) of Raymond Chen (Ms-Developer) where he quotes this:

> “If you want to dynamically change a window’s style to one that
> doesn’t support visible taskbar buttons, you must hide the window
> first (by calling ShowWindow with SW_HIDE), change the window style,
> and then show the window.”

And also points out a weak point of some programs and why they lose or get a blank taskbar icon:

> - Window is taskbar-eligible.
> - Window becomes visible ? taskbar button created.
> - Window goes taskbar-ineligible.
> - Window becomes hidden ? since the window is not taskbar-eligible at this point, the taskbar ignores it.

Anyway, the basic idea is the following:

1. Get the [handle of the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/relationship-between-a-cpp-window-object-and-an-hwnd?view=msvc-170). (Parent window of the root in this case for tkinter related reasons)
2. [get the current style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960886(v=msdn.10)) in a [hexadecimal code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles)
3. alter the hexadecimal code to your need with a bitwise operation
4. [apply the altered style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) to the window

I added the following code at the beginning of your script:

```
from ctypes import windll

GWL_EXSTYLE=-20
WS_EX_APPWINDOW=0x00040000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW=0x00000080

def set_appwindow():
    global hasstyle
    if not hasstyle:
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
        style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        style = style & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
        style = style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
        res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
        root.withdraw()
        root.after(100, lambda:root.wm_deiconify())
        hasstyle=True
```

This code at the end of your script:

```
hasstyle = False
root.update_idletasks()
root.withdraw()
set_appwindow()
```

and added the line `set_appwindow()` in `def frame_map(event=None):`. Als I had to implement another additional two lines in `def minieme1_(event=None):` to update the `hasstyle`variable.

So the overall implementation of this approach was possible to have your window ready and withdrawn for described reason. An additional variable to avoid a infinite loop while you alter the style of your window that is either `True` while it is shown or False while it is iconyfied, alongside with your overrideredirect method.

### Full Code

```
from tkinter import*
from ctypes import windll

GWL_EXSTYLE=-20
WS_EX_APPWINDOW=0x00040000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW=0x00000080

def set_appwindow():
    global hasstyle
    if not hasstyle:
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
        style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        style = style & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
        style = style | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
        res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
        root.withdraw()
        root.after(100, lambda:root.wm_deiconify())
        hasstyle=True
    
def move(e):
    xwin = root.winfo_x()
    ywin = root.winfo_y()
    startx = e.x_root
    starty = e.y_root
    ywin -= starty
    xwin -= startx
    def move_(e):
        root.geometry(f"+{e.x_root + xwin}+{e.y_root + ywin}")
    startx = e.x_root
    starty = e.y_root
    frame.bind("<B1-Motion>",move_)
def minieme1_(event=None):
    global hasstyle
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.state("iconic")
    hasstyle = False
def frame_map(event=None):
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.update_idletasks()
    set_appwindow()
    root.state("normal")
def minimefunction(event=None):
    global size
    if size:
        root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height-40}+0+0")
        minimsi.config(text=" \u2752 ")
        size = False
    else:
        root.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
        minimsi.config(text=" \u25a0 ")
        size = True
            
def quitApp():
    root.destroy()
def close_blink(event=None):
    close_button.config(bg="red")
def close_blink1(event=None):
    close_button.config(bg="gray19")
def minimsi_blink(event=None):
    minimsi.config(bg="gray29")
def minimsi_blink1(event=None):
    minimsi.config(bg="gray19")
def minimsi1_blink(event=None):
    minimsi1.config(bg="gray29")
def minimsi1_blink1(event=None):
    minimsi1.config(bg="gray19")
root = Tk()
size = True
app_width = 600
app_height = 500
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
print(screen_width,screen_height)
x = (screen_width/2) - (app_width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (app_height/2)
root.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
root.overrideredirect(True)
frame = Frame(root,bg="gray29")

Label(frame,text="My App",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray29",fg="white").pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
close_button = Button(frame,text=" X ",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",relief=GROOVE,borderwidth=0,command=quitApp)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
minimsi = Button(frame,text=" \u25a0 ",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",relief=GROOVE,borderwidth=0,command=minimefunction)
minimsi.pack(side=RIGHT)
minimsi1 = Button(frame,text=" - ",font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",relief=GROOVE,borderwidth=0,command=minieme1_)
minimsi1.pack(side=RIGHT)
frame.pack(fill=X)

yscroll = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL)
yscroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
editor = Text(font="Consolas 15",bg="gray19",fg="white",insertbackground="white",borderwidth=0,yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
yscroll.config(command=editor.yview)
editor.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)
root.config(bg="gray19")

frame.bind("<Button-1>",move)
frame.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
# minimsi1.bind("<Button-1>",minieme1_)
frame.bind("<Map>",frame_map)
close_button.bind("<Enter>",close_blink)
close_button.bind("<Leave>",close_blink1)
minimsi.bind("<Enter>",minimsi_blink)
minimsi.bind("<Leave>",minimsi_blink1)
minimsi1.bind("<Enter>",minimsi1_blink)
minimsi1.bind("<Leave>",minimsi1_blink1)

hasstyle = False
root.update_idletasks()
root.withdraw()
set_appwindow()


root.mainloop()
```

> Tested with python 3.10 and windows 11

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hidden root window to let the system window manager to show an icon in the taskbar, and make the custom window as a *transient child window* of the hidden root window in order to simulate those iconify and deiconify effect.

You need to bind `<Button>` event on the custom window so to bring it to the front when it is clicked.  Also need to bind `<FocusIn>` event on the hidden root window to move the focus to the custom window instead.

Below is the required changes:

```py
...
def minieme1_(event=None):
    # iconify hidden root window will iconify the custom window as well
    hidden_root.iconify()
...
def quitApp():
    # destroy the hidden root window will destroy the custom window as well
    hidden_root.destroy()
...

def on_focus(event):
    # bring custom window to front
    root.lift()

# create a hidden root window
hidden_root = Tk()
hidden_root.attributes('-alpha', 0)
hidden_root.title('My App')
# you can use hidden_root.iconbitmap(...) or hidden_root.iconphoto(...) to set the icon image

# use Toplevel instead of Tk for the custom window
root = Toplevel(hidden_root)
# make it a transient child window of hidden root window
root.transient(hidden_root)

root.bind('<Button>', on_focus)
hidden_root.bind('<FocusIn>', on_focus)
...
#frame.bind("<Map>",frame_map) # it is not necessary and frame_map() is removed as well
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't do this purely with Tkinter. You *can* set the window's icon via `self.iconbitmap(path_to_icon)`, but in order to have a unique taskbar icon, you'll need to compile your app into a Windows executable.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484185/8512262)

Edit: Unrelated, but as a matter of practice it's best to avoid star imports, e.g. `from tkinter import *` - it's much better to use something like `import tkinter as tk` and then prefix your Tkinter objects with `tk.` to avoid namespace pollution!