# How to disable window movement in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quick question, is there any way I can prevent a Tkinter window from being moved by the mouse? I couldn't seem to find any answers on google so I'm asking my own question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may could refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671011/disable-window-move-in-tkinter-python).

Comment: I have seen this but I couldn't see how the answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is by Using

```
Overrideredirect(1)
```

However this will ignore completely all window functions from the os window manager.
If you want the rest of the functions you will have to create a new fake window title bar yourself and assign all the functionalities you need (window close, minimize, maximize)

Comment: How would I create this fake title bar?

Comment: Have a look here. A little old post but I am sure it can help, or you can look for similar examples around. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter#23836427]

Comment: I feel like this solution is unoptimal. I'll just add a close window button