# Python tkinter won't remove the frame that i set to pack_forget()

Tags: python, tkinter

So I just learn tkinter and want to create a custom titlebar and change it colors base on login and signup page. I manage to change the color between login frame and signup frame. However I struggle changing the color of the tittle bar, I tried many functions like **pack_forget()**, **lift()**, **loop frame.winfo_children() and destroy widget**

the problem is I cannot manage to remove the frame of title when switching between login and signup page.

for convenient this is the source code : https://github.com/SeakMengs/Sign-in-gui-with-python-tkinter

```
class tittle():
    def __init__(self):

        global FrameBG, FontFG, BoxBG, SignupBG, SignupFG, SignupBOX, LoginBG , LoginFG, LoginBOX
        global inLogin, inSignup

        if inLogin == True:
            FrameBG, FontFG, BoxBG = LoginBG, LoginFG, LoginBOX
        if inSignup == True:
            print('change to purple')
            FrameBG, FontFG, BoxBG = SignupBG, SignupFG, SignupBOX

        self.root = root
        self.titlebar = Frame(root, background=FrameBG, bd=0)

    def titleBar(self):
        # ? Create my own titlebar
        global RunOnce

        root.overrideredirect(True)
        root.after(10, lambda: self.set_appwindow(root))
        # self.titlebar = Frame(root, background=FrameBG, bd=0)
        #*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # ? these functions copy from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217105/tkinter-overridedirect-minimizing-and-windows-task-bar-issues
        self.titlebar.bind('<Button-1>', self.SaveLastClickPos)
        self.titlebar.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.Dragging)
        self.titlebar.bind("<Map>", self.frameMapped) # This brings back the window
        #*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.icon = Image.open('asset\\bank.png')
        self.icon = self.icon.resize((22, 22))
        self.icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.icon)
        Label(self.titlebar, text='  Yato Bank', font=('Lexend', 16), bg=FrameBG, fg=FontFG, image=self.icon, compound=LEFT).pack(side=LEFT, pady=10, padx=10)

        # ? Open image using pil (for resize purpose)
        self.closeIcon = Image.open("asset\\close.png")
        self.closeIcon = self.closeIcon.resize((24, 24))
        self.closeIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.closeIcon)
        Button(self.titlebar, image=self.closeIcon, command=root.destroy, background=FrameBG, bd=0, activebackground=FrameBG).pack(side=RIGHT, pady=10, padx=10)

        self.maximizeIcon = Image.open("asset\\maximize.png")
        self.maximizeIcon = self.maximizeIcon.resize((24, 24))
        self.maximizeIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.maximizeIcon)
        Button(self.titlebar, image=self.maximizeIcon, command=self.fullScreen, background=FrameBG, bd=0, activebackground=FrameBG).pack(side=RIGHT, pady=10, padx=10)

        self.minimizeIcon = Image.open("asset\\minus.png")
        self.minimizeIcon = self.minimizeIcon.resize((24, 24))
        self.minimizeIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.minimizeIcon)
        Button(self.titlebar, image=self.minimizeIcon, command=self.minimizeGUI, background=FrameBG, bd=0, activebackground=FrameBG).pack(side=RIGHT, pady=10, padx=10)

        self.titlebar.pack(expand=0, fill=BOTH)

        RunOnce += 1

        if RunOnce > 1:
            self.titlebar.pack_forget()
            self.titlebar.pack(expand=0, fill=BOTH)
            self.titlebar.lift()
            pass
    def startBar(self):

        self.titlebar.pack_forget()
        tittle().titleBar()
        print("Destroyed")
```

These functions are for switching between signin and signup page and it call **class tittle() and its functions**

```
    #* switch frame
    def startLogin(self):

        global inLogin, inSignup
        inSignup = False
        inLogin = True

        # tittle().titlebar.destroy()
        # tittle().startBar()
        self.form.pack(expand=1)
    
    def changeToSignup(self):

        global inLogin, inSignup
        inSignup = True
        inLogin = False

        tittle().startBar()
        self.form.pack_forget()
        signupPage().startSignup()

    def startSignup(self):

        global inLogin, inSignup
        inSignup = True
        inLogin = False
        
        # tittle().titlebar.destroy()
        # tittle().startBar()
        self.signupFrame.pack(expand=1)

    def changeToLogin(self):

        global inLogin, inSignup
        inSignup = False
        inLogin = True

        tittle().startBar()
        self.signupFrame.pack_forget()
        loginPage().startLogin()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not clearly defined the variable name of the title bar. I thought it was `self.titlebar`. You have commented the line in which you defined the titlebar. And the second confusing point is where you are calling the pack_forget function. I thought that is in `if condition` in the `titlebar()` function. If so, you are directly packing the frame after unpacking the frame which makes no sense. First try to debug yourself, then post the question.

Comment: Basically I tried to debug for many hours and tried a lot of solutions already but after hours of trying I get overwhelmed and decide to ask for help and the code in my class is a mess because I'm trying to find a solution then after solving the problem I will remove the unnecessary parts!
Anyway thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Remove the unnecessary parts and then post the code. Sometimes they are the lines causing the bugs

Comment: I forgot about this, i wrote a simpler code that  explains what i need and a guy remind me to use configure and it solves the problem already here's the link to a new question i post ytd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034743/python-tkinter-how-to-change-the-color-of-frame1