# Python Tkinter how to change the color of frame1?

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I have three frames, I have one frame that stay forever and two frames switch between each other. However, everytimes I switch between frame2 and frame3 I want frame1 to change its background color following the frame2 or frame3's background color

```
from tkinter import *

global color1, color2, color3, inFrame2, inFrame3
color1 = ''
color2 = 'green'
color3 = 'yellow'
inFrame2 = True
inFrame3 = False

global count
count = 0

class frame1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root

        global color1, color2, color3, count
        global inFrame2, inFrame3

        if inFrame2 == True:
            color1 = color2
        elif inFrame3 == True:
            color1 = color3

        self.frames1 = Frame(root, background=color1)

        Label(self.frames1, text='page1', width=25, height=5, background=color1).pack()

        self.frames1.pack()
        count += 1
        print("run {} times".format(count))
    
    def changeColor(self):
        self.frames1.pack_forget()

class frame2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        global color1, color2, color3
        self.frames2 = Frame(root, background=color2, width=50, height=50)

        Label(self.frames2, text='page2', width=25, height=5, background=color2).pack()
        btn2 = Button(self.frames2, text='page2', background=color2, command=self.changeFrame)
        btn2.pack()

        self.frames2.pack(pady= 10)
    
    def startFrame2(self):
        self.frames2.pack()

    def changeFrame(self):

        global inFrame2, inFrame3
        inFrame2 = False
        inFrame3 = True

        self.frames2.forget()
        frame1().changeColor()
        frame3().startFrame3()


class frame3():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        global color1, color2, color3
        self.frames3 = Frame(root, background=color3, width=50, height=50)

        Label(self.frames3, text='page3', width=25, height=5, background=color3).pack()
        btn3 = Button(self.frames3, text='page3', background=color3, command=self.changeFrame)
        btn3.pack()

        self.frames3.pack(pady=10)

    def startFrame3(self):
        self.frames3.pack()

    def changeFrame(self):

        global inFrame2, inFrame3
        inFrame2 = True
        inFrame3 = False

        self.frames3.forget()
        frame1().changeColor()
        frame2().startFrame2()


def main():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')

    frame1()
    frame2()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[This is  frame1 and frame2, it has the same color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVI95.png)

[This is frame1 and frame3, but I want frame1 to change its color to yellow like frame3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWWcb.png)

Comment: Are you aware you can call the `configure` method to change any configuration option of any widget?

Comment: Oh dear god, thank you for your suggestion, I just recently learned tkinter although I know configure but I wasn't smart enough to think about that! now it works thank to your suggestion :)

```

Answer (score 0):

So to help people who might have the same problem in the future this is how I solve the problem thank to @Bryan Oakley

Use configure to change the background of frame1 in **def changeFrame(self):** function like this

```
        def changeFrame(self):
            global inFrame2, inFrame3
            global label, frames1
            inFrame2 = False
            inFrame3 = True

            label.configure(bg=color3)
            frames1.configure(bg=color3)
            self.frames2.forget()
            frame3().startFrame3()
```

This is how the code look like after solving the problem

```
from tkinter import *

global color1, color2, color3, inFrame2, inFrame3
color1 = 'red'
color2 = 'green'
color3 = 'yellow'
inFrame2 = True
inFrame3 = False

global count
count = 0

class frame1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root

        self.frames1 = Frame(root, bg=color1)

    def frame11(self):
        global label, frames1
        frames1 = Frame(root, background=color1)
        label = Label(frames1, text='page1', width=25, height=5, background=color1)
        label.pack()
        frames1.pack(fill=BOTH)
    


class frame2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        global color1, color2, color3
        self.frames2 = Frame(root, background=color2, width=50, height=50)

        Label(self.frames2, text='page2', width=25, height=5, background=color2).pack()
        btn2 = Button(self.frames2, text='page2', background=color2, command=self.changeFrame)
        btn2.pack()

        self.frames2.pack(pady= 10)
    
    def startFrame2(self):
        self.frames2.pack()

    def changeFrame(self):

        global inFrame2, inFrame3
        global label, frames1
        inFrame2 = False
        inFrame3 = True

        label.configure(bg=color3)
        frames1.configure(bg=color3)
        self.frames2.forget()
        frame3().startFrame3()


class frame3():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        global color1, color2, color3
        self.frames3 = Frame(root, background=color3, width=50, height=50)

        Label(self.frames3, text='page3', width=25, height=5, background=color3).pack()
        btn3 = Button(self.frames3, text='page3', background=color3, command=self.changeFrame)
        btn3.pack()

        self.frames3.pack(pady=10)

    def startFrame3(self):
        self.frames3.pack()

    def changeFrame(self):
        global label, frames1
        global inFrame2, inFrame3
        inFrame2 = True
        inFrame3 = False

        label.configure(bg=color2)
        frames1.configure(bg=color2)
        self.frames3.forget()
        frame2().startFrame2()


def main():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')

    frame1().frame11()
    frame2()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```