# PysimpleGui no icon in taskbar when using use_custom_titlebar = True

Tags: python, user-interface

I have run into several problems wanting to customize windows in Pysimplegui using `use_custom_titlebar = True`.

My system:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.1
- PySimpleGUI 4.38.0

Problems:

1. The icon does not appear on the taskbar, it only appears when I
   minimize the window. Consequently, if my window is hidden under
   another window of another application, I will not be able to access
   it or know that it is open until I have removed the window above it
   by covering it. I also can't access doing `alt+tab`
2. I can't disable the maximize window option. The argument `resizable = False` does not seem to affect the behavior. It also doesn't work if
   I set a fixed window size with the `size` argument

I appreciate in advance any contribution. **Thank you**

Example code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.B('Exit', size = (12,3))]]
window = sg.Window('My window',
                     layout,
                     use_custom_titlebar = True,
                     size = (None, None),
                     resizable = False)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None,'Exit'): 
        break
window.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use_custom_titlebar=True` sets `no_titlebar=True` for your window. Under Windows, this sets `window.TKroot.wm_overrideredirect(True)`, causing the (system) window manager to ignore the window. As one of the consequences, there is no taskbar icon.

[Tcl/Tk documentation: wm overrideredirect](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M56)

There are some tricks to deal with it when working directly with Tkinter (see, e.g., [Making Tkinter windows show up in the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066027/making-tkinter-windows-show-up-in-the-taskbar)) but we cannot do this directly via PySimpleGUI so far. Currently, I'm exploring how to make a dummy window to appear in the taskbar and to couple it with my window, but I don't have a working solution yet.

To keep my main window accessible even if it's behind another window, I'm using a system tray that always stays on top. (You may want to consider setting `keep_on_top=True` for your window, but sometimes it's simply not convenient.)

To prevent maximisation, you can either tweak the function `Titlebar()` in PySimpleGUI and comment out its part where the maximise-symbol is added like this:

```py
    return Column([[Column([icon_and_text_portion], pad=(0, 0), background_color=bc),
                    Column([[T(SYMBOL_TITLEBAR_MINIMIZE, text_color=tc, background_color=bc, enable_events=True, font=font, key=TITLEBAR_MINIMIZE_KEY),
                             # Text(SYMBOL_TITLEBAR_MAXIMIZE, text_color=tc, background_color=bc, enable_events=True, font=font,key=TITLEBAR_MAXIMIZE_KEY),
                             Text(SYMBOL_TITLEBAR_CLOSE, text_color=tc, background_color=bc, font=font, enable_events=True, key=TITLEBAR_CLOSE_KEY),
                             ]],
                           element_justification='r', expand_x=True, grab=True, pad=(0, 0), background_color=bc)
                    ]],
                  expand_x=True, grab=True,  background_color=bc, pad=(0,0),metadata=TITLEBAR_METADATA_MARKER, key=key)
```

or you can remove the titlebar completely using `no_titlebar=True` in your window and add your own titlebar at the beginning of your layout, for example with this function (tweaked from https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Window_Background_Image.py):

```py
titlebar = [sg.Col([[sg.Text(your_titlebar_text, text_color=tc, background_color=bc, font=font, grab=True)]],
                   pad=(0, 0), background_color=bc),
            sg.Col([[sg.Text(sg.SYMBOL_X, background_color=bc, enable_events=enable_events)]],  # '❎'
                   element_justification='r', key='-X-', grab=True, pad=(0, 0), background_color=bc)]
```

(you may want to add `sg.HorizontalSeparator()` as an extra row in the titlebar).

As an example:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

titlebar = [[sg.Col([[sg.Text('My window', grab=True)]], pad=(0, 0)),
             sg.Col([[sg.Text(sg.SYMBOL_X, enable_events=True, key='-X-')]],  # '❎'
                    element_justification='r', grab=True, pad=(0, 0), expand_x=True)],
            [sg.HorizontalSeparator()]]

layout = titlebar + [[sg.B('Exit', size=(12, 3))]]
window = sg.Window('My window', layout, no_titlebar=True, finalize=True)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event)
    if event in (None, 'Exit', '-X-'):
        break
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent lenka_cizkova !! I tried commenting on the line you indicated in pysimplegui.py and it worked. Then I decided to uncomment it and put the value enable_events = False to the text object, so that it continues to appear visible but without functionality

Comment: I believe it can be confusing for the user to have GUI elements that are visible and seem to be enabled - but not executing their usual action. But if you think it's a good solution in your case: why not... :)